# Query suggestion via REST API

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, 2016

While using Search Query Suggestion REST API in SP2016 On-Premises, we are not getting expected results.
e.g. searching for ‘data’ should show up ‘database tuning’, ‘database optimization’ but it does not, there are zero suggestions.

When searched for ‘database’ (the complete word) only search suggestion is ‘database’ i.e. the same word.

How to achieve the same using REST API endpoint used is

> http://sitename/search/_api/suggest?querytext=%27text%27

Please note that we have also updated Query suggestion enabled in SharePoint and imported few words as like

Database
Performance Tuning
Performance Testing
Sample Suggestion

Comment: I believe that query suggestions don't perform partial matches.

Comment: is there any better alternative to achieve the same?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I only came across it today while troubleshooting on of my farms' query suggestions not showing at all.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. will see if someone tried any alternatives and replies back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got reply from Microsoft team saying below

> the Query suggestion REST API does not support partial match, we need to use a full word for getting the related query suggestions in REST API.
>   If you want to make users be able to type a part of the word to get the search suggestions auto populated, then you can use OOTB search box instead.